# Ricci scalar algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is this derivation correct?
If $R=0$, $R$ being the scalar curvature, then:
$$R_{;k}=0$$
$$(g^{ac}g^{bd}R_{abcd})_{;k}=0$$
$$g^{ac}g^{bd}(R_{abcd})_{;k}=0$$
$$R_{abcd;k}=0$$

Comment: Careful, remember you are using Einstein notation, then a summation is envolved in your computations.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry, I forgot I cannot cancel terms as if it were a simple multiplication...

Comment: the $;$ is covariant derivative?

Comment: Yes, it is the covariant derivative.

Comment: This is anyway untrue; $R_{;k} = 0$ is the constant scalar curvature condition, whereas $R_{abcd;k}$ is the generally much stronger condition that the metric is locally symmetric. The notions do coincide in dimension $2$, where there is only one independent component of curvature.